# how to access uid + accesstoken outside of FB.Event.subscribe?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

Im sucessfully run FB.Event.subscribe and can output the `uid` and `accesstoken` from within that function - however **im wondering how i'd go about accessing `uid` and `accesstoken` from basically anywhere**?

My initial thought was that I needed to declare a global uid and accesstoken var outside of the function - however i've had no luck with that so far - when trying to output the global var I just get `undefined`

**My code just after the starting `<body>` tag:**

```
<body>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
//Declaring global var for uid and token
var uid;
var accessToken;

$(document).ready(function(){

  function facebookReady(){
    FB.init({
      appId      : '357646666347166', // App ID
      channelUrl : '//localhost/channel.html', // Channel File
      status     : true, // check login status
      cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
      xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
      });

    $(document).trigger("facebook:ready");
  }

  if(window.FB) {
    facebookReady();
  } else {
    window.fbAsyncInit = facebookReady;
  }
});

  // Load the SDK asynchronously
  (function(d){
   var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
   if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
   js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
   js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
   ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
  }(document));
</script>
```

**My code placed just before the closing `</body>` tag' - this is also where I try to access the global uid and token:**

```
<script>
$(document).on("facebook:ready", null,  function(){

    FB.Event.subscribe('auth.authResponseChange', function(response) {
      // Here we specify what we do with the response anytime this event occurs. 
      if (response.status === 'connected') {
// Setting the uid + token
        uid = response.authResponse.userID;
        accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;
//
      }
    });

        // Trying to access the UID OR TOKEN HERE:   
          console.log(uid);
          console.log(accessToken);
        // Trying to access the UID OR TOKEN HERE:   
});

</script>
<!-- some included js file where I also want to access the UID -->
<script src="js/animation.js"></script>
```

Comment: That’s because the JS SDK works asynchronously – the data has not yet arrived when you try to access it. Once the callback function has assigned the values to the variables, you will be able to access them “from anywhere” – but not before.

Comment: Hi cbroe, thanks so much for your comment. Would you by any chance have any suggestions on an approach, that would enable to wait for it to be set before i try to access it in the scope of my posted code?

Answer (score 0):

I use to just store my accessToken in a global variable and it worked w/o problems. The problem here is that both uid and accessToken only have scope within their respective script tags so the uid and accessToken declared within FB.Event.subscribe are their own values; separate from your "global variables" and who's scope is limited to FB.Event.subscribe.

That being said all you need is to use is **FB.getAccessToken()**

Example with using jQuery to retrieve data through an ajax request:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "myQuery.php",
    data: { accessToken: FB.getAccessToken() }
}).done(function(data) {
    doStuff(data);
});
```

You can also retrieve the uid through **FB.getUserID()**